# MIPS instructions to extract a field from a register

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, cpu-registers, mips32

The answer in the solutions manual seems wrong for this bitfield extraction problem.  My issues with it are posted below.

---

Here is the setup:
[image: Exercise 2.14.1a]

The question posed is:

> Find the shortest sequence of MIPS instructions that extracts a
>   field from $t0 for the constant values i = 22 and j = 5 and places the field into $t1
>   in the format shown in the data table.

The solutions manual gives this as the answer:

> ```
> lui $t1, 0x003f
> ori $t1, $t0, 0xffe0
> and $t1, $t0, $t1
> srl $t1, $t1, 5
> ```

I have 2 questions:

1. **Zeros to the right**. How does this proposed answer ensure that all bits to the right of "Field" in register $t1 are all zeroes?
2. **Shift Right Logical**. Isn't the last instruction supposed to be `sll $t1, $t1, 10` instead?

Comment: 2. Yes, I think it needs to end with a left-shift to put the field at the top of the register.  One easy way to do this would be right shift the field to the bottom, then left shift to the top.  Unless shift instructions are really slow on MIPS, two shifts should be better than 4 instructions.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what my answer was before I checked the solutions. Thanks for the edits as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty obvious that the answer in the solutions manual is less than ideal.

> 1. **Zeros to the right**. How does this proposed answer ensure that all
>      bits to the right of "Field" in register $t1 are all zeroes?

With the right combination of `andi` and `sll`, we can zero all the bits we need to zero.

> 2. **Shift Right Logical**. Isn't the last instruction supposed to be sll
>      $t1, $t1, 10 instead?

It's quite clear that this should be a `sll` operation instead of a `srl` operation.

Comment: I feel funny answering my own question, so if I've violated any etiquette, please let me know.

Comment: An OP answering your own question is encouraged if you found the solution before anybody else. Also, you may have gotten multiple answers for different parts of your question using different methods. So, if 5 responders provide 20% each, upvote them, and post your own combined answer [attribution is nice]. If one answer was 90% upvote and accept it. Upvote the other good answers. Here a comment under the 90% is sufficient, possibly detailing what you added. Most questions don't get self answered, mainly, because they get such good answers from others. It's mostly about avoiding redundancy.

Comment: For simple(r) stuff, you can edit your question, and _append_ the changed code to the bottom. _Never_ edit the original code--it changes the nature of the question and invalidates the responses (i.e. they no longer make sense). You can do this if you wish or not. Again, a judgement call

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! I'll keep those in mind next time I have to to do this.

Comment: Writing up a nicely-formatted answer that explains the solution is a good way to make it useful for future readers.  It's totally fine even if comments helped you figure out what the answer was.  It's great that you took my comment and turned it into a well-written answer, since I wasn't going to take the time to do that.  Writing and formatting answers is useful work that takes time, so you certainly get to take credit for that.  You can make an answer "community wiki" to avoid taking credit if you're just copy/paste comment without adding any value, but that's not the case here.